# Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home/crevisio/public_html/matisoff.info/white/coinbase/payment.php on line 7

Tags: php

What's wrong with this code?

Idk why but the formatting is messed up on here.  It's the line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

I'm new here and all help is appreicated.  Thanks.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['payment'])){
    require('config.php');
    $ch= curl_init('https://coinbase.com/api/v1/account/generate_receive_address');
    $amount=$_POST['amount'];
    $json=json_encode(array("api_key"=>COINBASE_APIKEY,"address"=>array("callback_url"=>$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'callback.php')));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $jsonreturn=json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
    if(is_integer($amount) && $amount>0 && $jsonreturn['callback_url']==$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'callback.php'){
        $mysql=new mysqli(MYSQL_HOSTNAME,MYSQL_USERNAME,MYSQL_PASSWORD,MYSQL_DATABASE);
        $mysql->query("INSERT INTO invoices(Amount, Address) VALUES ('$amount','".$jsonreturn['address']."')");
        $mysql->close();
        header('refresh: 1;url=payment.php?address='.$jsonreturn['address'].'&amount='.$amount);
        exit();
    }else{
        header("refresh: url=payment.php?error=1");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is actually with the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS` line. (line numbers start from the beginning of the file, not just counting lines of PHP code)

The actual PHP constant is [`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php) (singular), not `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS`.

Because of the way PHP handles undefined constants, it generates a warning message (probably hidden due to your config settings), and treats the undefined constant as a string: `"CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS"` - thus the error message about expecting an integer (long), and getting a string.

### Updated

If you're still not getting the results you expect from your code, I'd check the following:

1. Your connection parameters - where do the hostname, username, password, etc come from? are you sure they're correct.
2. You haven't properly escaped your variable values before inserting them into your query. If you've got quotes in your values, it'll cause problems. Try `echo`ing out your sql instead of querying it, and then try to run it manually against your database. I'd also **highly** recommend looking into using [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496) instead.

Comment: The error is gone but it's not inserting into the DB or redirecting.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JakeMcLaughlin I've updated my answer with some more suggestions.

Comment: @JakeMcLaughlin If you continue to have problems, it's really a different issue from what this question is about (curl error message), and I'd recommend asking it as a new question - after first debugging as much as possible yourself.

Comment: They come from config.php.  Wouldn't I get errors if it was the second option?

Comment: Is there a PM system on here?  Could you help me elsewhere?